# Get Server folder from a server IP

Tags: c#

How to get the folder of a server for ex: 170.1.1.1 there is a folder Info in C:\, using c# is there a way to get C:\info drive for a server?

Am not able to get it right?

Answer (score 3):

If there is no share on this folder or on c:\ but the user that runs the app has admin-rights, try to open `\\IP-Address\c$\info\filename.txt`

```
string path = @"\\IP-Address\c$\info\filename.txt"
if (File.Exists(path)){
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)){
        string s = "";
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: No the user doesn't have admin rights, is it something to do with server.mappath()? Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem is about permissions. If you can setup a share for the directory your app wants to access and give the user that runs your app access rights (if its an asp.net-app, then the corresponding iis-user must have the rights), then you can access the file with \\IP-Address\shareName\filename.txt. But if you don't have a share, you can only access it over an administrative share such as c$, but for this, the user-account the app runs under, needs admin-rights. MapPath is utility function that maps a relative or virtual address of an asp-web-resource to a physical path on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Only if that server is sharing that folder somehow.  Are you talking about browsing it as a network share?  Getting a directory listing from a web server?

Comment: I need to access a file from a server from C:. If its a local machine i can give path like C: or D:, how do i look for server IP's folder. for say i need to get files from IP/Info/File1.txt, for say how to access File1.txt from a server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool folderBrowseDialog and into properties change SelectedPath into your desired IP-Address.

If you are using button to activate codes, insert this.

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtfilename.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }  
    }
```

Hope it will helps...